# How do I resolve: "error C2039: 'cstr' : is not a member of 'std::basic_string"?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class ListIndexOutOfRangeException : public out_of_range
{
public:
    ListIndexOutOfRangeException(const string & message = "") : out_of_range(message.c_str())
    {
    }
}; // end ListIndexOutOfRangeException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`out_of_range` accepts a string reference, so just use

```
: out_of_range(message)
```

instead.

edit:

And as others have said, the compiler is telling you you have used `message.cstr()` instead of `message.c_str()`. But the method call is unnecessary anyway, just pass the string.